# objective-c change to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I do not know how to convert the following Objective-C code into swift. How should I do ?

Objective-c

```
if (operations) {
    if ([operations isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id <MyOperation> operation in operations) {
            if (operation) {
                [operation cancel];
            }
        }
    } else if ([operations conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyOperation)]){
        [(id<MyOperation>) operations cancel];
    }
    [operationDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
}
```

swift

```
if operations != nil {
        // doto .......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if operations != nil {
    // doto .......
    if (operations?.isKindOfClass(NSArray) != nil){
        for operation in operations as! [MyOperation]{
            operation.cancle()
        }
    } else if operations?.conformsToProtocol(MyOperation){

    (operations as MyOperation).cancle()
}
    operationDictionary.removeObjectForKey(key)
}
```

I didn't test it so may be you have to make little bit changes into this code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't help people with complete conversions, but...

```
if let operations: AnyObject = operations {
    if operations is NSArray {
        for operation in operations as! [MyOperation] {
            operation.cancel()
        }
    }
    else if let operation = operations as? MyOperation {
        operation.cancel()
    }

    operationDictionary.removeObjectForKey(key)
}
```